# Function that gives minimum strokes required for a given array of strings

Tags: javascript, algorithm

It is given an array of strings. Strings have same length. Assuming input array is (["ababc", "abbba", "aaabb", "bcccb", "acbbb", "aaabb"]).

```
a b a b c
a b b b a
a a a b b
b c c c b
a c b b b
a a a b b
```

The problem is about finding minimum connected groups of letters, it is possible to sketch vertically and horizontally for the same letter but not diagonally. For this example, there are 4 groups for letter 'a' (two single, two multiple),
2 groups for letter 'b' (one single, one multiple) and 2 groups for letter 'c' (one single, one multiple). So, the output should be "8". I couldn't find a solution using JavaScript.

I've tried to consider it as seperate rows and columns. Moreover, creating arrays for each character and analyze it seperately. But never of them works correctly.

```
function strokesRequired(picture){
        let total = picture.join('');
        let strLength = picture[0].length;
        let counter = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < total.length; i++){
          if(total[i] !== total[i+1] || total[i] !== total[i+strLength] || total[i] !== total[i-1] || total[i] !== total[i-strLength]){
            continue;
         }
         else {        
            counter++;
          }      
        }
        return counter;    
      }
```

My code returns 4 for this problem but should return 8. Because I count just for the letters don't have any horizontally and vertically matches.

Comment: This smells like homework

Comment: What is a stroke in your example? Why should it be 8 not 4?

Comment: How your output should be `8` ?

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity. I hope I could ask it in the right way

Comment: "The problem is about finding minimum drawings required, it is possible to sketch vertically and horizontally for the same letter but not diagonally." Still not clear. How is the output 8 for this test case. ?

Comment: I think "drawing" is used to say "connected component": that is: how many connected groups of letters are there? In the example, there are 4 groups of a's (two singles and two multi-square groups), 2 b's and 2 c's. Is that right?

Comment: Yes you explained it very well. The problem asks for connected groups of letters. There are 4 groups of a’s (two singles and two multiple groups), 2 groups of b’s (one single and one multiple group) and 2 groups of c’s (one single and one multiple group).

Comment: Sorry for my English by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way that runs a depth first search from each cell that hasn't been visited. I think this can also be solved with a flood fill, merging component labels when a connection is revealed.

```js
function f(M){
  let m = M.length
  let n = M[0].length
  let visited = new Array(m)
  for (let i=0; i<m; i++)
    visited[i] = new Array(n).fill(0)
    
  function getNeighbours(y, x){
    let c = M[y][x]
    let neighbours = []

    if (y > 0 && !visited[y-1][x] && M[y-1][x] == c)
      neighbours.push([y-1, x])
    if (y < m - 1 && !visited[y+1][x] && M[y+1][x] == c)
      neighbours.push([y+1, x])
    if (x > 0 && !visited[y][x-1] && M[y][x-1] == c)
      neighbours.push([y, x-1])
    if (x < n - 1 && !visited[y][x+1] && M[y][x+1] == c)
      neighbours.push([y, x+1])

    return neighbours
  }
    
  function dfs(y, x){
    let stack = [[y, x]]
  
    while (stack.length){
      let [y, x] = stack.pop()
      visited[y][x] = 1
      stack.push(...getNeighbours(y, x))
    }
  }
  
  let count = 0
  
  for (let i=0; i<m; i++){
    for (let j=0; j<n; j++){
      if (!visited[i][j]){
        count++
        dfs(i, j)
      }
    }
  }
  
  return count
}

var M = [
  "ababc",
  "abbba",
  "aaabb",
  "bcccb",
  "acbbb",
  "aaabb"
]

console.log(f(M))
```